# How to make a dropdown comboBox spawn in multiple columns?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have search about this subject, but only have found the need of fill various columns with one comboBoxItem.
What I need is a list of a single column, warpped in various columns to shorten the overall length of the comboBox and in addition set some headers to delimit sections to make easier the search of one item.
Here a example of wath I'm looking for:

[image: multi columns ComboBox]

I'm messing up with grid.columns definitions inside the Popup tag in a ComboBox style, but I'm not getting the proper result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,51,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding CanSelect}" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool CanSelect { get; set; }
    }

    public class SelectableItem : Item
    {
        public SelectableItem()
        {
            CanSelect = true;
        }
    }

    public class Header : Item
    {
    }

    // inside constructor or wherever:
    var items = new Item[] {
        new Header() { Text = "Header1"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new Header() { Text = "Header2"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new Header() { Text = "Header3"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"},
        new SelectableItem() { Text = "ComboboxItem"}
    };
    comboBox1.ItemsSource = items;
```